# Adding a main class to an applet

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, applet, awt

I added a main method to a Java applet in order to run it as an application but it requires me to initialize all the methods in the class that contains the main.  I managed to initialize the `init` method but I have failed to initialize all methods that carry on arguments.

Any one with an idea on how to proceed?

Comment: Show us some code illustrating your problem.

Answer (score 6):

Here is code from a working application. Note how the applet methods are called:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(400, 300);

    final Applet applet = new MyCustomApplet();

    frame.getContentPane().add(applet);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
            applet.stop();
            applet.destroy();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    frame.setVisible(true);
    applet.init();
    applet.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

There is more to starting some applets than simply calling the `start()` and `init()` methods.  Many applets require a valid `AppletContext` and `AppletStub` in order to work correctly.

The best strategy would be to factor the GUI into a separate class that is added either to an applet or frame as needed.  This is called an 'hybrid application/applet'.  [Subway](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway) is a good example of an hybrid, though it does not accept arguments.  For the arguments, accept them in the constructor of the GUI class, or include get/set methods for them.  The applet would use `getParam(String)` to determine what values to use, while the application would get the arguments from the `String[]` from `main(String[] args)`.